# Resolving additional payment options?

Tags: interface, payment, process

I'm trying to make UX on service purchase (it can be any product or service). I have a mandatory "Fixed price" field and I can add **instalment options** if needed. Here is a popup.

[image]

I need to make user enter a fixed price (this is more like a global price), then if he wants to, he can add an instalment plan.
For example, I'm selling a mouse for 100$. I also want to add an instalment payment, 12 instalments, but for 110$ (do the math 110$/12=9.16, you get how much the instalment is).

After I added the option, it looks like this.
[image]

Help me figure out a better way of this process.

Comment: Your question isn't very clear - Is this interface for the service provider to set out options for their customers?

Comment: Yes, this is the place where admins create options that will show up for customers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My best reasoning was to separate time/period and pricing. We added template feature later on which made it obvious which inputs should go together. Idea was to visually separate related inputs to improve visual hierarchy (take it as small improvement).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what exactly you don't like about your current design, so I'll present a different option that might be interesting for your end-user.

One way is to have fixed instalment plans as you show here, but you can also give end-users more freedom in choosing how they will pay off their product. Depending on what kind of product it is, you may entice more end-users to purchase because you can tailor their purchase to their personal financial situation. This will be interesting for your own users because they want to sell more.

[image: Phone payment plan]

This is the example that came to mind; you can choose to pay a certain amount up front and have the rest be a loan. Or you can pay everything in advance and have no loan, or the whole amount can be a loan. This will show the amount paid up front and the corresponding monthly fee.

Comment: I don't like the fact its not clear that "Interest rate", "Instalment" and |Total price" are related. For example, if you fill out "Total price", it will calculate "Interest rate" and "Instalment" for you (using "Number of instalment" field). Also, if you fill out "Instalment", other two fields are calculated. Same goes for "Interest rate". Really like the suggestion on end user side tho we probably won't implement it in this version.

Comment: Check the new version: https://i.imgur.com/yHXZRZL.png